# Column into multiple columns with distinct count

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a table which looks like:

| event_date | event_name | user_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 20220407 | n1 | a |
| 20220407 | n2 | b |
| 20220407 | n3 | a |
| 20220408 | n1 | a |
| 20220408 | n1 | a |
| 20220408 | n2 | c |

Each row is presenting single event with params (it’s actually a bigquery table with data from firebase)

I want to select only needed events and place their sum for distinct users grouped by day into another table, like this:

| date | n1 distinct users count | n2 distinct users count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 20220407 | 1 | 1 |
| 20220408 | 2 | 0 |

I've tried smth like:

```
SELECT COUNT (DISTINCT user_pseudo_id) as users
,event_date 
event_name,  
case app_info.id when 'com.kaspersky.standalone-vpn' then 'KSeC-iOS'  
                    when  'com.kaspersky.secure.connection' then 'KSeC-Android'  
                    when  'com.kaspersky.securityadvisor' then 'KSC-iOS'  
                    when  'com.kaspersky.security.cloud' then 'KSC-Android'                      
                    else app_info.id end as product 
, SUBSTRING(device.language, 1, 2) as language  
, geo.country  
, app_info.version as app_version  
  FROM `ksec-android.analytics_156657667.events_*`
  WHERE (event_name = 'first_open' OR event_name = 'user_engagement' OR 'event_name' = 'app_remove') 
  and _table_suffix >= FORMAT_DATE("%Y%m%d",(date_sub(CURRENT_DATE(), interval 1 day)))
  group by event_date 
  ,product 
  ,language 
  ,country 
  ,app_version
  ,event_name
) src
pivot
(
  count(users)
  for event_name in ([first_open], [user_engagement], [app_remove])
) piv
group by event_date 
  ,product 
  ,language 
  ,country 
  ,app_version
```

I really don’t get it, would be so thankful for help

Comment: [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952). Also see [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551), which also applies to sample data and output.

Comment: Thank you! I'm informed about the rules, just didnt have an opportunity to get to me desktop. Now it's edited

Answer (score 1):

consider below approach

```
select * from your_table 
pivot (count(distinct user_id) as count for event_name in ('n1', 'n2'))
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

Comment: Thank you for answer! I came up with a pivot idea last days, but could not be sure if it's correct. Seems like now I'm on the right way

Comment: And it's really not needed to pick me into uploading pictures - i know perfectly about my fault :))) Already edited

Comment: great! edited too :o)